How not to excecute specific Azure Pipeline stage which is defined with a template
I have a Azure pipeline based on templates which are created by another team. I have no EDIT permissions for those templates. One of the stages of the pipeline is:
  - template: oo-templates/d-template.yaml@RepoTemplates
    parameters:
      stage: 'Test_Deployment' 

It is visible when I run the pipeline from the portal:

I would like to temporary disable it from the code. I have tried to add condition like this:
  - template: oo-templates/d-template.yaml@RepoTemplates
    parameters:
      stage: 'Test_Deployment' 
      condition: false

but it did not bring any effect.
Is there any other flag or any other way to "switch off" given stage? preferably in that way that it will be "disabled" be default in the stages list when running the pipeline.

When you queue a new pipeline, all available stages will be selected in the "Stages to run" section. There is no way to automatically deselect a specific stage.
You can control which stages are generated when a pipeline starts, though.
Example
Consider a simple pipeline with 2 stages - Build and Deploy:

If you don't want the Deploy stage to run by default you can define a boolean parameter named deployApplication set to false:
# my-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  - name: deployApplication
    displayName: 'Deploy Application'
    type: boolean
    default: false # <-------------- Don't deploy by default

stages:
  - template: /pipelines/stages/build-deploy-stages.yaml
    parameters:
      deployApplication: ${{ parameters.deployApplication }}

Stages template:
parameters:
  - name: deployApplication
    displayName: 'Deploy Application'
    type: boolean

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: job_Build
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo Build
  
  - ${{ if parameters.deployApplication }}: # <--------- generate stage based on parameter
    - stage: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      dependsOn: Build
      jobs:
        - job: job_Deploy
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: echo Deploy

Queuing a new pipeline - default values:

Deploy stage won't be generated so it won't be visible in "Stages to run":

Selecting "Deploy Application":

Deploy stage is now visible in "Stages to run":


I forgott to add in my question that  templates  are created by another team. I have no EDIT permissions for those templates.

@fascynacja if you or someone else have a good use case for changing the templates why don't you ask the owners of the templates to do it? It's a very simple change and easy to implement in a backward-compatible way.

yes I can ask for that change. But of course I put here very simplified example, in real life there are many stages and many paramteres involved.

@fascynacja my suggestion of using boolean parameters is still valid, no matter how many stages you have  :-)  Now it is up to you (and the owners of the shared templates) to change the pipelines and corresponding templates in such a way that is easy to use. For example, the other team could create additional templates for specific use cases and then you could use boolean parameters to choose between template X or Y.

"in real life there are many stages and many paramteres involved" - another option would be to split these stages among several pipelines in order to reduce complexity.

yes here as always will come the question, if they want to do that, And also if they will decide to do that they will probably need to do it in a holistic way, and maybe create similiar conditions for all stages so everything is clear. Your answer is very valid in that case.

@fascynacja if you think my answer is useful please consider accepting and/or upvoting it. Thanks!

@fascynacja one last thing - you might want to share some suggestions of mine on how to create extensible templates - the link is for jobs, but the same concern applies to stages as well

before I accept the answer, can you tell me if there is any way to achieve "disabling" of the stage, even for it not to be visible in the stages choice, directly from my yaml?

@fascynacja if you can't edit the template your only option is to render the whole template (i.e. all stages in the template) or not, using something like ${{ if parameter.renderTemplate }} .... Other settings like setting conditions in the stages, etc require modifications to the template.
